# NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, permission-denied

I tried to make an app that sends messages from iPhone to Bluetooth LE module. But for some reason, it gives the following error:

> **NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted**.

Even though the types of the ***blePeripheral*** and the ***blePeripheral!.write*** are `CBCharacteristicWrite.withResponse`, the error says that writing is not permitted. How come the following code does not work for me?

```
func writeValue(data: String) {
    let valueString = (data as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    //change the "data" to valueString
    if let blePeripheral = blePeripheral {
        if let txCharacteristic = txCharacteristic {
            blePeripheral.writeValue(valueString!, for: txCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
        }
    }
}

func writeCharacteristic(val: Int8) {
    var val = val
    let ns = NSData(bytes: &val, length: MemoryLayout<Int8>.size)
    blePeripheral!.writeValue(ns as Data, for: txCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
}
```

The resource where I found the code is: 
https://learn.adafruit.com/crack-the-code/communication

Comment: "the types of the blePeripheral and the blePeripheral!.write are CBCharacteristicWrite.withResponse" You mean the properties of `txCharacteristic`?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, txCharacteristic is for sending messages from my phone to a BLE module. So I am trying to permit the phone to send the data, but why does the xcode says to me that the permission is not allowed?

Comment: When you did in `didDiscoverCharacterstic()` :`txCharacteristic = characteristic`, could you add print("tx properties: \(txCharacteristic.properties)") and give the output?

Comment: The app prints the following statements: `Found 1 characteristics!` 
`Rx Characteristic: FFE1`
`Tx Characteristic: FFE1`

Comment: It doesn't answer if the property is writable or not.